# When is queue sync task from the method return executed?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I am browsing through the source code from `Alamofire` and the following snippet makes me a bit confused.

```
    func task(session: URLSession, adapter: RequestAdapter?, queue: DispatchQueue) throws -> URLSessionTask {
        do {
            let urlRequest = try self.urlRequest.adapt(using: adapter)
            return queue.sync { session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) }
        } catch {
            throw AdaptError(error: error)
        }
    }
```

The line `queue.sync { session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) }` makes me confused.

As you can see that the method return type is `URLSessionTask` which is exactly what `session.dataTask(with: urlRequest)` is returning.

The `queue.sync {}` is `func sync<T>(execute work: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T`, which in this case returns `URLSessionTask`.

So my question is when exactly does `session.dataTask(with: urlRequest)` inside `queue.sync {}` runs? is it when the method reaches this line before actual returning or when the returned object being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of `sync` in Apple's documentation says:

> **sync(execute:)**
>
> Submits a block object for execution on a dispatch queue and waits
>   until that block completes.

So that closure runs immediately on the `queue`. The returned value of the function is the returned value of the closure inside `sync`.

Comment: I have to add that I didn't realise there's a version of `sync` with a return value. Great to know!